# PHP Get Image size when image is stored as byte array

Tags: php, gd, getimagesize

I have image as binary string. (submitted via POST from C# app as byte array)

I can read it using imagecreatefromstring function.
How can I get image size (width and height)?

getimagesize function takes filename as parametar. 
Is there alternative that can read image from binary string and return image size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`imagesx`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesx.php) and [`imagesy`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesy.php) on gd resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try `imagesx();` and `imagesy();`